# download file with blob from asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I want to download an excel from my angular controller using blob.

the server code of the mvc application is

```
    [HttpGet]    
    public HttpResponseMessage Download(SearchModel search){
        string fileName = "test.xls"

        byte[] file = GetFile(search)
        HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)

        HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage();                    
        httpResponseMessage.Content = new ByteArrayContent(file.ToArray());                    
        httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.Add("x-filename", fileName);                    
        httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");                    
        httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new    ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");                    
        httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = fileName;                    

        return httpResponseMessage;   
    }
```

and the js

```
$http({ method: 'GET', url: 'Download', params: {...some params}, responseType: 'arrayBuffer' })
    .success(function (data, status, headers) {

        headers = headers();
        var filename = headers['x-filename'];
        var contentType = headers['content-type'];
        var linkElement = document.createElement('a');
        try {
            if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
                window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(new Blob([data],{type: "application/octet-stream"}));
                return;
            }

            var a = $("<a style='display: none;'/>");
            var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data], {type: "application/octet-stream"}));
            a.attr("href", url);
            a.attr("download", "name");
            $("body").append(a);
            a[0].click();
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
            a.remove();
        }
        catch (ex) {
            console.log(ex);
        }
    })
    .error(function () {  });
```

but there are some problems:

1. the filename in the javascript side is undefined and not test.xls as in the server side
2. the contentType is "text/html; charset=utf-8" and not "application/octet-stream" as in the server side
3. the file that is downloaded is this

> ```
> StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content:  System.Net.Http.ByteArrayContent, Headers:
> {
>   x-filename: test.pdf
>   Content-Type: application/octet-stream
>   Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.pdf
> }
> ```

The file is a JSON with header information .
Why is this file wrong?

Comment: That means your controller is not asp.net web api, but regular asp.net mvc (so inherits from `Controller` and not `ApiController`).

Comment: you should post your "my computer" here

Comment: Thank you @Evk. That is the problem. I've resolved using FileResult.